# Remove empty string in list in Julia

Tags: list, julia

I am looking for efficient solution to remove empty string in a list in Julia.

Here is my list :

```
li = ["one", "two", "three", " ", "four", "five"]
```

I can remove empty string by using *for loop*, as following :

```
new_li = []
for i in li
    if i == " "
    else
        push!(new_li, i)
    end
end
```

But I believe there is more efficient way to remove the empty string.

Comment: Just fyi, loops are plenty fast in Julia. There are ways to shorten your code and make it easier to understand, but they may not change the speed much. The idea of "avoiding loops because they're slow" comes from languages that have slow loops so they need to make functions that use other languages' fast loops, e.g. R using C++.

Comment: @BatWannaBe Oh, Thank you!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
new_li = filter((i) -> i != " ", li)
```

or

```
new_li = [i for i in li if i != " "]
```

Comment: `filter(!=(" "), li)`

Answer (score 6):

I have a couple of comments a bit too long for the comments field:

Firstly, when building an array, never start it like this:

```
new_li = []
```

It creates a `Vector{Any}`, which can harm performance. If you want to initialize a vector of strings, it is better to write

```
new_li = String[]
```

Secondly, `" "` is not an empty string! Look here:

```
jl> isempty(" ")
false
```

It is a non-empty string that contains a space. An empty string would be `""`, no space. If you're actually trying to remove empty strings you could do

```
filter(!isempty, li)
```

or, for in-place operation, you can use `filter!`:

```
filter!(!isempty, li)
```

But you're not actually removing empty strings, but strings consisting of one (or more?) spaces, and maybe also actually empty strings? In that case you could use `isspace` along with `all`. This will remove all strings that are only spaces, *including* empty strings:

```
jl> li = ["one", "", "two", "three", " ", "four", "   ", "five"];

jl> filter(s->!all(isspace, s), li)
5-element Vector{String}:
 "one"
 "two"
 "three"
 "four"
 "five"
```

Comment: that was a nice answer!